# how to develop multiple authentication chat system using users and admins

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, chat

I am developing a chat system that allows teachers(admins table) and students(users table) to log in and send messages to each other using a chat function with laravel.
I was able to develop chat system between only students and was able to develop multi login function, which means that the teachers can login as a teacher and the students can login as a student.
But I can't develop chat function between the teacher and student.
How can I develop this?
I'm sorry to trouble you, but I would appreciate it if you could help me!!
The following code is the code at the time of implementing the chat function and multiple logins between students.

～MsgController.php～

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Msg;
use App\Chat;
use Auth;

class MsgController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'msg' => 'required',
            'c_id' => 'required',
        ]);
        $cu = Auth::user()->id;
        $msg = new Msg;
        $msg->msg = $request->msg;
        $msg->user_id = $cu;
        $msg->chat_id = $request->c_id;
        $msg->seen = 0;
        $msg->save();

        if (!empty($msg)){
            $resp["status"] = 1;
            $resp['txt'] = "Successfully Create A New Msg";
            $resp['obj'] = $msg;

            $c = Chat::find($request->c_id);
            $resp['count'] = count($c->msgs);
            $count = count($c->msgs);
            if ( $count > 1 ) {
                $resp['fst'] = 0;
            }else {
                $resp['fst'] = 1;
            }
        }else {
            $resp["status"] = 0;
            $resp['txt'] = "Something went wrong!";
        }
        return json_encode($resp);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function message_list(Request $request)
    {
        $chat = Chat::find($request->c_id);
        if ($request->limit > 10) {

            $total = $chat->msgs()->orderBy("id", "desc")->get();

            if (count($total) < $request->limit + 10) {
                $resp['end'] = true;
            }

            $msgs = $chat->msgs()->take($request->limit)->skip($request->limit - 10)->orderBy("id","desc")->get();
        }else {
            $msgs = $chat->msgs()->take($request->limit)->orderBy("id","desc")->get();
        }
        $me = Auth::user();

        if (!isset($resp['end'])) {
            $resp['end'] = false;
        }

        $resp['status'] = 1;
        $resp['txt'] = (string) view('layouts.msg_list', compact("msgs", "me"));
        return json_encode($resp);
    }


    public function new_message_list(Request $request)
    {
        $chat = Chat::find($request->c_id);
        $me = Auth::user();
        if ($request->me == 1) {
            $msgs = $chat->msgs()->where('seen','=',0)->where('user_id','=',$me->id)->orderBy("id","desc")->take(1)->get();
        }else {
            $msgs = $chat->msgs()->where('seen','=',0)->where('user_id','<>',$me->id)->get();
        }
        if ( count($msgs) > 0){
            $resp['status'] = 1;
            $resp['txt'] = (string) view('layouts.msg_list', compact("msgs","me"));
        }else{
            $resp['status'] = 2;
        }

        
        return json_encode($resp);
    }
    

    public function message_seen(Request $request)
    {
        $ck = Msg::where('seen', '=', 0)->where('chat_id', '=', $request->c_id)->where('user_id','<>', Auth::user()->id)->update(['seen'=>1]);
        if ($ck) {
            $resp['status'] = 1;
        }else {
            $resp['status'] = 0;
        }
        return json_encode($resp);
    }
}
```

～ChatController.php～

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Chat;
use App\User;
use Auth;


class ChatController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'users' => "required"
        ]);

        $chk_chats = Auth::user()->chats;

        $already_exist = "";
        foreach ($chk_chats as $ct) {
            $un = [];
            $already_exist = false;
            foreach ($ct->users as $u) {
                if (Auth::user()->id != $u->id) {
                    $un[] = (string)$u->id;
                }
            }

            if ($request->users == $un) {
                $already_exist = true;
                break;
            }else{
                $already_exist = false;
            }
        }

        if (!$already_exist) {
            $chat = new Chat;
            $chat->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $chat->save();
            $chat->users()->attach(Auth::user()->id);
            foreach ($request->users as $id) {
                $chat->users()->attach($id);
            }
            if (!empty($chat)) {
                $resp['status'] = 1;
                $resp['txt'] = "Successfully Created A New Chat";
                $resp['obj'] = $chat;
                $resp['objusers'] = $chat->users;
            }else{
                $resp['status'] = 0;
                $resp['txt'] = "Something went wrong!";
            }
        }else{
            $resp['status'] = 0;
            $resp['txt'] = "Chat Already Exist!";
        }

        return json_encode($resp);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.

     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function chat_update()
    {
        $chats = Auth::user()->chats()->orderby('id','desc')->get();
        $total_msg = Chat::chat_update($chats);

        return json_encode($total_msg);
    }

    public function chat_list()
    {   
        $chats = Auth::user()->chats()->orderby('id','desc')->get();
        $me = Auth::user();
        $total_msg = Chat::chat_update($chats);
        $resp['status'] = 1;
        $resp['txt'] = (string) view('layouts.chat_list', compact("chats","me",'total_msg'));
        return json_encode($resp);
    }
}
```

～ActiveChatController.php～

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Activechat;
use App\User;
use Auth;


class ActiveChatController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'c_id' => 'required'
        ]);
        $cu = Auth::user()->id;
        $chk = Activechat::where('user_id','=',$cu)->first();
        if ( !empty($chk)) {
            $chk->chat_id = $request->c_id;
            $chk->save();
        }else{
            $active = new ActiveChat;
            $active->chat_id = $request->c_id;
            $active->user_id = $cu;
            $active->typing = false;
            $active->save();
        }

        if (!empty($active) || !empty($chk)) {
            $resp['status'] = 1;
            $resp['txt'] = "Success";
        }else {
            $resp['status'] = 0;
            $resp['txt'] = "Something went wrong!";
        }

        return json_encode($resp);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function set_active(Request $request)
    {
        $cu = Auth::user()->id;
        $chk = Activechat::where('user_id','=',$cu)->first();

        if ( !empty($chk) ) {
            $chk->typing = $request->con;
            $chk->save();
        }

        if ( !empty($chk) ) {
            $resp['status'] = 1;
            $resp['con'] = $request->con;
        }else {
            $resp['status'] = 0;
        }

        return json_encode($resp);
    }



    public function check_active(Request $request)
    {
        $cu = Auth::user()->id;
        $chk = Activechat::where('chat_id','=',$request->c_id)->where('typing','=',1)->get();

        $usr = [];
        if ( count($chk) > 0 ) {
            foreach ($chk as $value) {
                $u = User::find($value->user_id);
                if ($u->id != $cu ) {
                    $usr[] = $u->name;
                }
            }

            if (count($usr) == 1 && $usr != Auth::user()->name && $usr != null ) {
                $resp['user_name'] = $usr;
                $resp['txt'] = 1;

            }elseif (count($usr) > 1 ) {
                $resp['user_name'] = implode(",", $usr);
                $resp['txt'] = 1;
            }else {
                $resp['txt'] = 0;
            }


        }else {
            $resp['txt'] = 0;
        }

        if ( count($usr) > 0 ) {
            $resp['status'] = 1;
        }else {
            $resp['status'] = 0;
            $resp['txt'] = "something went wrong!";
        }

        return json_encode($resp);
    }

}
```

~app.blade.php~

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'KigyouDe') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-select.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]) !!};
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Kigyoude') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <h5>自分の名前をクリックしてプロフィール画像を設定してみよう！</h5>

                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @if (Auth::guest())
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus font-weight-bold"></span> New Chat
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ route('reset_password') }}">
                                    reset password
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('profile') }}">
                                            Profile
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                    document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>
                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

@if(Auth::user()):
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Create New Chat</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="create-chat-status"></div>
            <form id="create-form">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Select Users</label>
                        <select id="create-data" class="selectpicker" multiple>
                        @if(isset($users))
                            @foreach($users as $user)
                                <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                        </select>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button data-deselectAllText="Deselect All" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="close">Close</button>
            <button disabled type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="create">Create</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
@endif
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

~chat_list.blade.php~

```
@if( count($chats) > 0 )
    @foreach($chats as $chat)
    <div id="{{$chat->id}}" class="chat-item">
        @if( count($chat->users) > 2 )
            <img src="{{ asset('img/default-group.jpg') }}" class="img-circle img-responsive chat-item-img">
        @else
            <?php
                foreach ($chat->users as $u) {
                    if ($me->id !== $u->id) {
                        $img = $u->pic;
                        $id = $u->id;
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <img src="{{ asset('img/'. $img) }}" class="img-circle img-responsive chat-item-img">
            <a href="/show/{{$id}}">Check Profile</a>
        @endif
        <div class="chat-item-users">
            <?php
                $un = [];
                foreach ($chat->users as $u) {
                    if ($me->id !== $u->id) {
                        $un[] = $u->name;
                    }
                }
                $un = implode(", ", $un);
                echo ( strlen($un) > 17 ) ? substr($un, 0, 17) ."...":$un;
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
            if ( array_key_exists($chat->id, $total_msg) ) {
                $c = ($total_msg[$chat->id] > 20 ) ? "20+" : $total_msg[$chat->id];
                echo "<div class='new-msg-count'>". $c ."</div>";
            }
        ?>

    </div>
    @endforeach
@else
    <div class="no-record text-center">No chat Exist</div>
@endif
```

~msg_list.blade.php~

```
@if( count($msgs) > 0 )
    @if( count($msgs) == 1 )
        @foreach($msgs as $msg)
            <div id="{{$msg->id}}" class="msg-item <?php echo ($msg->user_id == $me->id) ? 'me' : ''; ?>">
            
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/'.$msg->user->pic) }}" class="img-circle img-responsive msg-item-img">

                <div class="msg-item-txt">
                    {{$msg->msg}}
                <div class="msg-item-data">
                    @if( $msg->created_at->diffInHours(\Carbon\Carbon::now(), false ) > 24 )
                        {{$msg->created_at->format('d F Y h:i A') }}
                    @else
                        {{$msg->created_at->diffForHumans()}}
                    @endif
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @else
        @foreach($msgs->reverse() as $msg)
            <div id="{{$msg->id}}" class="msg-item <?php echo ($msg->user_id == $me->id) ? 'me' : ''; ?>">
            
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/'.$msg->user->pic) }}" class="img-circle img-responsive msg-item-img">

                <div class="msg-item-txt">
                    {{$msg->msg}}
                    
                <div class="msg-item-data">
                    @if( $msg->created_at->diffInHours(\Carbon\Carbon::now(), false ) > 24 )
                        {{$msg->created_at->format('d F Y h:i A') }}
                    @else
                        {{$msg->created_at->diffForHumans()}}
                    @endif
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@else
    <div class="no-record text-center">No Message Exist</div>
@endif
```

~the tables of database~

```
users table...id,name,email,self_production,pic,password,remember_token,created_at,updated_at
chats table...id,user_id,created_at,updated_at
activechats table...id,user_id,chat_id,typing
chat_user table...chat_id,user_id,created_at,updated_at
migrations table...id,migration,batch
msgs table...id,msg,chat_id,user_id,seen,updated_at,created_at
password_resets table...email,token,created_at
```

Comment: If you have a chat function between students, what's the difference between that and having chat between students and teachers? I haven't the time to read your __entire__ codebase to figure it out, you should really narrow down the exact problem and post just that part of the code. In what way does it not work now?

Comment: Looking at your database tables, I can't see anything in there that would indicate a difference between a student and a teacher. Do you have a column in the user record to show the difference, that you've missed off the post?

Comment: Thank you for a comment. In this chat system, you can select which person to talk to. When I have only students table, students and teachers are displayed together in select place where you choose people. To prevent that, I must have two table. About database tables, it is shown only for only students because I'm not sure how to change the tables.

Comment: Why must you have two tables? Just have a column that denotes "student" or "teacher", and select them as required.

Comment: Please,could you explain more carefully?

Comment: I can't think of another way to put it. What is the difference between a teacher and a student, from the point of view of your system? What can one do that the other cannot, and why does that require a separate table? If you are storing different information in the teachers table, then fair enough. But if you just need to distinguish one from the other, a simple "user type" column with "S" or "T" in it would do.

Comment: Isn't it impossible that students can only select teachers and teachers select only students??

Comment: I wanna show the teachers' self_introduction and students' self_introduction. So, with only teachers column or students column, I cannot make it.

Comment: I have solved it! Thank you droopsnoot!!

Comment: Perhaps you could add more information, in case it helps anyone who finds this question in the future.

Comment: Could you share your solution, I have same problem, and i going create another table for store information of teacher and student together and when any update we also need update this table also